# Setting up Charles Proxy on mobile hotspot

Tags: charles-proxy

My system is set up and runs Charles Proxy fine when I am on regular home Wi-Fi. It isn't working when I have connected the mobile and the laptop/Mac to a hotspot. Is there a special step associated with hotspots to enable Charles Proxy on hotspot. It seems both mobile internet and macOS internet stops working if I have Charles Proxy running on the laptop or macOS Proxy setup on the laptop and proxy running on the client mobile. I have not done any special setup for the hotspot client.